# silent closing VS 2008 on Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, building

I am trying to build a MFC Windows Application with Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7. I use the "Batch build" feature of Visual Studio to get both Release and Debug of several projects' outputs with only one-click.

The problem is: Frequently, after I instruct VS 2008, some minutes later VS closes its window without any explanation. I have already seach the Web about these things and it seems that nobody as an answer.

I cannot be more specific than this. VS simply closes and you will not get any information.

Thanks in advance,

Sérgio

Comment: I'd say it's just bad luck. :( Unless you can trace things with Process Monitor and actually find something wrong, I don't think you'll get much of an answer, since there's obviously not enough information for diagnosis (not saying that it's your fault).

Comment: What about asking Microsoft about this?

Comment: @sergiol: "VS closes its window" -- what window are you talking about?

Comment: Wouldn't you normally do this with an msbuild script?

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev: the main window of Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: @David Heffernan: Why? If I have this integrated int he UI of VS, I don't need a script.

Comment: @sergiol you just don't know yet that you need to script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that installing the patch quoted on http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2009/03/widely-reported-crash-in-visual-studio-2008-sp1-fixed.ars solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I could give would be to contact Microsoft directly and let them know of your problem. If there is no error information, it could be that they are not handling an exception and the program is just closing instead.